# SQLalchemy:Incorrect string value

Tags: python, string, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert data from Facebook Marketing API into my database, but I got this

```
Error: (pymysql.err.DataError) 
      (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9D\\x97\\x96\\xF0\\x9D...' 
      for column 'fp_name' at row 1")
```

but after I checked it there's the styling (bold text) in the string that I'm trying to insert, like this picture below:

[image]

Any suggestion is really meant to me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks a lot of details. Like which SGBD you use even though I guess it's MySQL. But I just had a similar error.

Possible solutions are:

- add ?charset=utf8 at the end of your connection string
- be sure that you installed the package named mysql-connector-python
- be sure that your SGBD is MySQL and not MariaDB

Hope it will help somebody